# Multiple imputation constraining for not applicable values

Tags: spss, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I want to do a multiple imputation of missing data using SPSS. I have a nominal (categorical) variable X with **missing values** codified as '9' and **not applicable** values codified as '8'.

How can I constrain imputed values to X, for not imputing '8' (not applicable) to a '9' (missing value)?

Since this variable X is categorical it is not possible in SPSS to use 'Define Constraints' for that purpose. Is this possible using other application for multiple imputation (e.g. R)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want SPSS to impute any possible values EXCEPT 8 (not applicable)? You don't want SPSS to impute 8s, is that it?

Comment: Yes, I don't want SPSS to impute 8s because 'not applicable' values  should be defined in a deterministic way: a missing value cannot be a 'not applicable' by 'chance'.